# How to fill dropdown when its master Dropwnlist change event works on table row

Tags: asp.net, jquery

[image]`ddlInjuryType` and `ddlInjurySubType` are two dropdown placed in same row that row will dynamically clone to next row on add button click. following code not filling "`ddlInjurySubType`"

```
$("#tblSurgery").on('change', 'select.ddlInjuryType', function (event) {
     $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Surgery.aspx/FetchInjurySubType",
                        data: JSON.stringify({ typeId: $(this).val(), locale: 'en-US' }),
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.d.length > 0) {

                                $(this).find(".ddlInjurySubType").empty().append("<option value='0'>--Select Injury Type--</option>").append(data.d);

                            }

                        }
                    });
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer

```
 $("#tblSurgery").on('change', 'select.ddlInjuryType', function (event) {
    var trIndex= $(this).closest('tr').index();


         $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Surgery.aspx/FetchInjurySubType",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ typeId: $(ddlInjuryType).val(), locale: 'en-US' }),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.d.length > 0) {

                                    $("#tblSurgery tr:eq(" + trIndex+1 + ")").closest("tr").find(".ddlInjurySubType").empty().append("<option value='0'>--Select Injury Sub Type--</option>").append(data.d);

                                }

                            }
                        });
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code with following

```
    $("#tblSurgery").on('change', 'select.ddlInjuryType', function (event) {

event.stopPropagation();
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
var ddlInjuryType = $(this);

         $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "Surgery.aspx/FetchInjurySubType",
                            data: JSON.stringify({ typeId: $(ddlInjuryType).val(), locale: 'en-US' }),
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (data) {
                                if (data.d.length > 0) {

                                    $(ddlInjuryType ).parent().parent().find(".ddlInjurySubType").empty().append("<option value='0'>--Select Injury Type--</option>").append(data.d);

                                }

                            }
                        });
        });
```

Comment: Ok answer is updated use ".parent().parent()" instead of single ".parent()"

Answer (score 1):

There is a scope issue in your code, `this` doesn't refer to the changed element. You should cache the `this` object outside the `success` handler:

```
var _this = this;
```

Then you can use the cached object in your success handler, or the  set the `context` property to `this`:

```
$.ajax({
   context: this,
   // ...
})
```

Comment: when i used  `context: this,` code worked but, every row `ddlInjurySubType` dropdown fill on each event

Comment: @user2119324 Does this mean that the handler should be called once? If it's the case you can use `one()` method instead of `on()`.

Comment: no sir, in multiple rows i placed `ddlInjuryType` dropdown each one has its `ddlInjurySubType` dropdrown.